# .NET PDF Library that can wait for javascript to execute before generatign a PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking for an alternative to ABC PDF. We currently use ABC PDF in a way I haven't seen in other libraries.

would like to create a pdf file from a url that has client side javascript to retrieve data. I need to wait for this data to load before I create the PDF file. ABC.PDF does this by applying a client side handle and waits until this is set to true before processing the html.

It would also be a plus if we were able to inject some javascript into the url source to run, this is less important though.

are there any other .NET libraries out there that has functionality similar to this.

I have investigated ITextSharp and found that does not offer what I am looking for.
I have also looked into Essential Objects PDF and although this comes close, again does not achieve what I am looking for.
Aspose PDF is another I have looked into and see I cant do as I describe.

Comment: You might want to try Selenium to use an actual or emulated (HtmlUnit) browser to load the page and execute JavaScript. After that is finished you can try to retrieve the generated page source and use it as input for a HTML-to-PDF transformer. (Beware, you have to test whether the browser returns the constructed HTML content or not; the HtmlUnitDriver returns the constructed source but Selenium warns that not all drivers do.)